# How to apply 2way binding for input type file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a hidden input with type file. onChange prop bind to onchange handler, where i get a value and save in state. In case of input type file, i save in state event.target.files[0]. - a file.

Here is an input:

```
<input type='file' onChange={props.changed} value={props.value} />
```

One way binding works well. I save my file in state, but when i rerender component, input become an empty and i have this error:

**react-dom.development.js:2427 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.**

How to set value correctly from the state? I tried to make something **props.value.name**, but not succeed

Comment: have you tried to save event.target.files ?

Comment: Because you use input file you can't do that. Only for other input except from file.